# How to convert date time input string with optional time into UNIX time using java.time

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I'm using java.time to convert date time to unix time but the result is not always correct when I have different input formats. In the code below the output is not correct. It converts "2016-06-21-10-19-22" to 2016-06-21T00:00:00+00:00.

If the input is "04/28/2016", "MM/dd/yyyy", the result is correct.

I want to know how to write a function that can convert both date with time and date without time to the correct timeInSeconds?

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
        String dateTimeString = "2016-06-21-10-19-22";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);

        ZonedDateTime resultado = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

        Instant i = resultado.toInstant();
        long timeInSeconds = i.getEpochSecond();
        int nanoAdjustment = i.getNano();

        System.out.println("" + timeInSeconds + " seconds " + nanoAdjustment + " nanoseconds");//1466467200 seconds 0 nanoseconds
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code, let me try listing one by one

1. You are always parsing the input string into [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), even it is representing with time

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2016-06-21-10-19-22", formatter);  //2016-06-21 

LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2016-06-21", formatter);  //2016-06-21
```

2. After parsing the input string into `LocalDate`, you are always converting it into [ZoneDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) with starting time of the day which is `00:00:00`

```
 ZonedDateTime resultado = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC"));   //2016-06-21T00:00Z[UTC]
```

3. And finally you are converting same `ZonedDateTime` into [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) irrespective of time from input, which is why you are getting same result always

```
Instant i = resultado.toInstant().getEpochSecond();  //1466467200
```

The best to achieve this problem will be using [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseBest-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery...-) with optional time representation in formatter, and using [parseBest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseBest-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery...-)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd[-HH-mm-ss]");

TemporalAccessor dt = parser.parseBest(dateTimeString, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);

if (dt instanceof LocalDateTime) {
       (LocalDateTime) dt).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
  } else {
       (LocalDate) dt).atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Deadpool, I tried parseBest() but still got the wrong answer, I edit my question please take a look.

Comment: Check my updated code, the order in `parseBest` matters @zzxdw

Comment: Thanks for your help